# Previous Month Recall formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to open a file that has a title with the previous month in its name. For instance the file name is formatted as such: NAME year Month.xlsx. Currently I can get it to pull January, however the current month is May so I need April.

Below I have the current code that is pulling up only January. I need the month to be in format "mm". I have run the code without `FileMonth = Month(Date - 30)` which gave me the previous month number but in single digit format rather than double digit. (for April file it searched for coding as 4 instead of 04). the current code does search for January as 01. As well as if I omit `-30` then it will pull May as 05.

```
Dim Path As String
Dim FileYear As String
Dim FileMonth As String
FileYear = Year(Date - 30)
FileMonth = Format(Month(Date - 30), "mm")
Path = "C:\User\NAME " & FileYear & " " & FileMonth
Workbooks.Open (Path)
```

The only error is the wrong file being pulled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

`FileMonth = Format((Date - 30), "mm")`

Thanks,
Hafeez

Comment: @TonyJeffs note that on March 1st this will return `01` not `02`

Comment: @TonyJeffs yes . replace this with Scott's code - FileMonth = Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "00")

Answer (score 1):

EDITED:
Thanks Tony for the heads up! Code is corrected to reflect the comments.

Use:

```
FileMonth = Format(Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "mm"), "00")
```

Problem with using 30 days is that not all months have that amount

You could simplify all:

```
Dim Path As String
Dim FileDate As String
FileDate = Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "yyyy mm")
Path = "C:\User\NAME " & FileDate
Workbooks.Open (Path)
```

Comment: Just a heads up, the first code searched for the file name using the full date in just a number format. The second one omitted spaces between year and month, but otherwise works.